# Scraping dynamic website with unchanging urls

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, xpath

I need to scrape data of all dental clinis. What's the next step? Can someone help me out? I have now 2 options of code:

1, Here i don't know how to set 'for loop' for all pages

```
url = "https://www.dent.cz/zubni-lekari"

s = HTMLSession()
r = s.get(url)
r.html.render(sleep=1)

for x in range(1, 31):

    clinic = r.html.xpath(
        f'//*[@id="main"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[{x}]/h3', first=True)
        
   

    adress = r.html.xpath(
        f'//*[@id="main"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[{x}]/p[1]', first=True)

    try:
        phone = r.html.xpath(
            f'//*[@id="main"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[{x}]/p[1]/strong[1]', first=True)
    except:
        phone = "None"

    try:
        email = r.html.xpath(
            f'//*[@id="main"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[{x}]/p[1]/strong[2]', first=True)
    except:
        email = "None"


    clinics_list = {
        "Clinic": clinic.text,
        "Adress": adress.text,
        "Phone": phone.text,
        "Email": email.text
        }

    print(clinics_list)
```

2, Here i don't know how to find out the rest of data (adresses, phone, email)

```
api_url = "https://is-api.dent.cz/api/v1/web/workplaces"

payload = {
    "deleted": False,
    "filter": "accepts_new_patients=false",
    "fulltext": "",
    "page": 1,                     # <--- you can implement pagination via this parameter
    "per_page": 30,
    "sort_fields": "name",
}

data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()

for item in data["data"]:
    print(format(item["name"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the page number.  And extract the information from the json response

```
api_url = "https://is-api.dent.cz/api/v1/web/workplaces"

payload = {
    "deleted": False,
    "filter": "accepts_new_patients=false",
    "fulltext": "",
    "page": 1,                     # <--- you can implement pagination via this parameter
    "per_page": 30,
    "sort_fields": "name",
}

PAGES = 233

for i in range(1, PAGES):
     payload['page'] = i
     response = requests.post(api_url, json=payload)
     data = response.json()
```

The output looks like this:

```
{'data': [{'id': 'df313eba-7447-4496-bca5-abd8a840394a',
   'name': '#staycool s.r.o.',
   'regional_chamber': {'id': 'ce0d8c8a-99db-46ed-85ff-87b6650c677a',
    'name': 'OSK UHERSKÉ HRADIŠTĚ',
    'checked': False,
    'code': '',
    'tooltip': ''},
   'provider': {'id': '256f41bd-a9f1-452b-99e7-63f77005ecfa',
    'name': '#staycool s.r.o.',
    'is_also_member': False,
    'registration_number': '11982861',
    'identification_number': '',
    'type_cares': []},
   'accepts_new_patients': False,
   'address': {'city': 'Uherské Hradiště',
    'state': '',
    'country_name': '',
    'print': 'J.E.Purkyně 365, 686 06 Uherské Hradiště',
    'street': 'J.E.Purkyně 365',
    'postcode': '686 06',
    'name': ''},
   'contact': {'email1': '',
    'email2': '',
    'full': '',
    'phone1': '',
    'phone2': '',
    'web': '',
    'deleted': False},
   'membes': [],
   'insurance_companies': []},
```

so we just need to extract the data from the dictionary inside the data list

```
for i in range(1, PAGES):
    payload['page'] = i
    response = requests.post(api_url, json=payload)
    data = response.json()
    for item in data['data']:
        clinic = item['name']
        address_city = item['address']['city']
        address_street = item['address']['street']
        address_postcode = item['address']['postcode']
        phone = item['contact']['phone1'] 
        email = item['contact']['email1']
```